# Can't mount Droid Incredible 2 to Windows 7 PC

Tags: android, adb, mount

I've been searching for the last 2 hours and can't figure this out.

I just finished developing an application with jquery mobile / phonegap, downloaded all the android sdk stuff, downloaded the google usb driver via sdk.

I've tried connecting my Incredible 2 numerous times in order to install ADB via device manager like everywhere on the internet was saying. But when I go to my device manager, there is nothing that says "Other Devices" just "Unknown Device" under usb ports...

Not sure, I've tried almost everything including modifying the google usb inf file to add support for the Incredible 2, still no luck after connecting. Not sure if I have to manually install the google driver or something? I just downloaded it with the sdk, haven't done more with it.

Comment: "mounting" actually has next to nothing to do with adb - if anything, it's an annoyance that can almost get in the way.  Many people doing development hardly ever mount the device's filesystem - if we need to move a file or two back and forth we use the adb push/pull commands, and the adb shell to look around (or there's a file browser in DDMS, but I'd avoid that too).  Most likely the use of "mount" in the title here is mistaken, though it could also be leading astray the effort to get adb working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to go to Settings->Applications on your phone and allow "Unknown sources".

Comment: Enabled that a while ago, no luck :(

Comment: Then there are three more things you can try (as you can tell, I've been in your shoes): 1) try another cable 2) restart adb with "adb kill-server" 3) restart the phone. At one time or another, each of these has worked.

Comment: None of that works :/ I have 2 different usb cables here and neither is working. Perhaps it's my phone itself, not completely sure. I have another android phone upstairs buried that I'll try and see if it works.

Comment: Now the device isn't even showing up when connected on my pc. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, the most critical thing to enable in settings is **USB Debugging**

Answer (score 0):

Braydon,

You will need to download HTC Sync from HTC. The link is: http://www.htc.com/www/help/htc-incredible-s/#download. I am assuming that you are using a windows PC, be sure to do a complete install. Once you have finished and connected your phone to your PC, you should see it appear in DDMS' device list. If you have problems after that let me know.

Rockncoder